# jQuery: Hide duplicate options based on data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I'm trying to use jQuery to hide duplicate `<option>` elements within a `<select>` based on a specific data attribute.

The options have `data-addon-name` and `data-variant-name` attributes. I want to hide the option with `data-variant-name="Default"` when there are duplicates with the same `data-addon-name`.

I've tried the following script, but it doesn't seem to work as expected:

Html:

```html
<div id="c-product-bundling">

  <select id="ropeEndFinish1" name="properties[End 1 Finish]" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="1">
    <option value="Splice Eyelet End w-Thimble" data-addon-name="Splice Eyelet End w-Thimble" data-addon-price="30.00" data-addon-id="47367371030849" data-variant-name="Default" style="display: initial;">Splice Eyelet End w-Thimble - $30.00</option>
    <option value="Splice Eyelet End w-Thimble" data-addon-name="Splice Eyelet End w-Thimble" data-addon-price="45.00" data-addon-id="47367371063617" data-variant-name="32mm" style="">Splice Eyelet End w-Thimble - $45.00</option>
  </select>

  Another select with the same thing.

</div>
```

Jquery

```js
// Function to hide the options with the same value and display only the one with variant-name="Default"
function hideOptionsWithSameValue() {
  // Iterate through each select element
  $("#c-product-bundling select").each(
    function () {
      const currentSelect = $(this);
      console.log(
        "%cBeing run for" + JSON.stringify(currentSelect, null, "\t"),
        "color: Cyan; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px"
      );

      // Object to store seen options based on their values
      const seenOptions = {};
      const duplicateDefaultOptions = {}; // Move this line inside the loop

      // Iterate through each option element
      currentSelect.find("option").each(function () {
        const currentOption = $(this);
        const optionValue = currentOption.data("addon-name");

        // Check if an option with the same value has been seen
        if (seenOptions[optionValue]) {
          // Record the duplicate option with variant-name="Default"
          if (currentOption.data("variant-name") === "Default") {
            duplicateDefaultOptions[optionValue] = true;
          }
        } else {
          // Mark the option as seen
          seenOptions[optionValue] = true;
        }
      });

      // Hide the duplicate options with variant-name="Default"
      for (const optionValue in duplicateDefaultOptions) {
        currentSelect
          .find(`option[value="${optionValue}"][data-variant-name="Default"]`)
          .css("display", "none");

        console.log(
          "%cDuplicate Default option hidden for value: " + optionValue,
          "color: Cyan; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px"
        );
      }

      console.log(
        "%cThese have been marked for seenOptions" +
          JSON.stringify(seenOptions, null, "\t"),
        "color: Cyan; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px"
      );
      console.log(
        "%cThese have been marked for duplicateDefaultOptions" +
          JSON.stringify(duplicateDefaultOptions, null, "\t"),
        "color: Cyan; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px"
      );
    }
  );

  console.log(
    "%cCompleted sorting through all Addon Selects",
    "color: Cyan; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px"
  );
}
hideOptionsWithSameValue();
```

Here is the codepen if you want to duplicate
https://codepen.io/leebaroneau/pen/oNmPVbB

What adjustments should I make to the script to ensure that it correctly hides the "Default" variant only when there are duplicates with the same `data-addon-name`?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question so it's a [mcve] with focus on the **minimal**? Make it clear which options should be hidden

Comment: @Phil Done! I updated the codepen and the question. I stripped as much as I could out.

Comment: Are you only wanting to search for duplicates within the parent `<select>` or across the entire document?

Comment: Search for duplicates within the parent <select> on every select inside the div id="c-product-bundling".

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to first find all the *Default* options then search for matches using their `data-addon-name`. If they exist, hide the original.

jQuery is completely overkill for a simple operation like this

```js
const selector = '[data-variant-name="Default"]';

document.querySelectorAll("#c-product-bundling select").forEach((select) => {
  select
    .querySelectorAll(`option[data-addon-name]${selector}`)
    .forEach((option) => {
      if (
        select.querySelector(
          `option[data-addon-name="${option.dataset.addonName}"]:not(${selector})`,
        )
      ) {
        console.log("Removing option", option.textContent.trim());
        option.remove();
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="c-product-bundling">
  <select
    id="ropeEndFinish1"
    name="properties[End 1 Finish]"
    data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="1"
  >
    <option
      value="Splice Eyelet End w-Thimble"
      data-addon-name="Splice Eyelet End w-Thimble"
      data-addon-price="30.00"
      data-addon-id="47367371030849"
      data-variant-name="Default"
      style="display: initial"
    >
      Splice Eyelet End w-Thimble - $30.00
    </option>
    <option
      value="Splice Eyelet End w-Thimble"
      data-addon-name="Splice Eyelet End w-Thimble"
      data-addon-price="45.00"
      data-addon-id="47367371063617"
      data-variant-name="32mm"
      style=""
    >
      Splice Eyelet End w-Thimble - $45.00
    </option>
  </select>

  <p>Another select with the same thing.</p>
</div>
```

Note that I've used `remove()` to completely remove the `<option>` as hiding the element can have unexpected effects when it comes to the current selection.

If you wanted to hide the element anyway, simply use this instead

```js
option.style.display = 'none';
option.hidden = true;
option.disabled = true;
```

---

If you're set on a jQuery solution, this is roughly equivalent

```js
$("#c-product-bundling select").each((_, select) => {
  const $select = $(select);
  $select
    .find(`option[data-addon-name]${selector}`)
    .each((_, option) => {
      const $option = $(option);
      const others = $select
        .find(`option[data-addon-name="${$option.data("addon-name")}"]`)
        .not(option);
      if (others.length > 0) {
        $option.remove();
      }
    });
});
```